# jQuery cannot take the user input when the form is submitted

Tags: php, jquery, forms, email, submit

I have the following piece of code. I need to check the validation of user input (his email address) while he submits the form. And if the email address doesn't have a correct format, an error message should be shown.

The problem is that when I enter a wrong email address in the textbox and press the submit button nothing happens. I used to check the code using alert (I wrote `alert("Email")`) and understood that `$("#customerEmail").val()` returns no value, while I have currently entered a value in the textbox. What could be the problem?

```
<form method="post" action="">
     <input type="text" id="customerEmail"/>
     <br/>
     <input type="submit" id="customerRegister" name="customerRegister"/>
</form>

<?php
  if(isset($_POST['customerRegister'])){
     echo'
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var EMail=$("#customerEmail").val();
       alert(Email);
       var atpos = EMail.indexOf("@");
       var dotpos = EMail.lastIndexOf(".");
           if (EMail != "")
       {
           if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= EMail.length) 
               {
                   $("#customerEmailSpan").html("wrong email address");
               }
           else if (atpos >= 1 && dotpos >= atpos + 2 && dotpos + 2 < EMail.length)
               document.getElementById("customerEmailSpan").innerHTML = "";
       }
    </script>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Why you just dont check first with jquery, and if its ok, trigger the submit of the form???

Comment: on a side note your customerEmail has no name.

Comment: You are mixing PHP which runs serverside with javascript, that runs clientside. In your script `$("#customerEmail").val()` will always be empty, since the page is just loaded, each and every time your javascript sees it.

Comment: I 've just checked it. Unfortunately I found nth.

Comment: try with $(document).ready(function() 
{ // your code here;} and also the path of your jquery.js

Comment: You are alerting a variable 'Email' (note the lower m) and the variable you are setting above it is 'EMail' (note the upper M).  That won't fix your issue but it does explain why the alert is empty

Comment: @Drew no it didn't solve the problem. But thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you do something like this instead of mixing js with php ?

Make a separate javascript file and put the js code here.

You are declaring EMail and alerting Email. This could be a reason.

```
(function($){

   //Call the script after document is loaded.
   $(document).ready(function() { 

      //on click event of submit button
      $("body").on("click", "#customerRegister", function(e){

       var EMail = $("#customerEmail").val();

       //This is the mistake you were doing. ie; print Email instead of EMail.
       alert(EMail);
       var atpos = EMail.indexOf("@");
       var dotpos = EMail.lastIndexOf(".");
           if (EMail != "")
       {
           if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= EMail.length) 
               {
                   $("#customerEmailSpan").html("wrong email address");
               }
           else if (atpos >= 1 && dotpos >= atpos + 2 && dotpos + 2 < EMail.length)
               $("#customerEmailSpan").val("");
       }


       });
    });

      }(jQuery));
```

Comment: Thanks sandesh. It worked. But can you explain more? I put your code in the php tags and my problem was solved. I really appreciate your help:)

Comment: Okay I will add explanation in answer.

Comment: I have added some explanation in comments.

Comment: Sorry sandesh, it seems your code prevents submitting the form. You have used preventDefault(), this causes clicking the "customerRegister" doesn't submit the form, instead it acts as a button! I need "customerRegister" works as a SUBMIT button and send the form content to the server.

Comment: Then you can remove e.preventDefault(); I have removed it.

Comment: OK. I guess I should manipulate it a bit more. THANKS FOR THE HELP AND TIME:)

Comment: You can use it after if condition where email is invalid.(If you want.)

Comment: Hi. Why you unaccepted the answer again? Please let me know if there is something in code where I can help.